# Interpreting a Confidence Interval Question

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, standardization

The mean time spent travelling daily by individual members of a population
is about $60$ minutes, with variance about $900$ minutes$^2$. A programme
is planned in which the travel patterns of $10$ individuals will each be
surveyed through a number of weeks. Estimate how many weeks will
be required in order for all of the $95$% confidence interval for the mean time spent travelling by an individual to be $5$% of the mean value that is observed. Comment on the resulting survey plan.

I am struggling to interpret this question, especially about how to account for the $5$% of the mean value. I would greatly appreciate some help in solving this.

Comment: Add  self-study tag.